# Specific vocabulary for making someone laugh by rubbing their underarm with finger

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, vocabulary

To make someone laugh, we sometime rub his underarm with our fingers in a way that makes him feel restless and then  he starts laughing. My question is: What is the specific vocabulary in the English language for the aforesaid rubbing?

Comment: Kashif I've edited your post because you wrote it wholly in lowercase. Bearing in mind that this is an English Language site, questions should please, as far as possible, be written in standard English format. It also makes them easier to read quickly. I don't mean that you have to be proficient in English, but please use it as best you can.

Comment: @TrevorD! Thanks alot. I wish I could upvote you for this editing.

Comment: On a side note, instead of just rubbing, I suggest applying some degree of light scraping/stroking (combined) for better results.

Comment: @GlauberRocha do you want me to substitute scraping/stroking for rubbing in my question? if so, why don't you edit my question!

Comment: @kashif Hell, no!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of giving too general a term, I would suggest the word "tickle". This would refer to rubbing any part of the body to elicit laughter.

Definition 2 here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tickle

Comment: Rats! ...and jinx!  You beat me by mere seconds Matt! I'll remove my answer. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez why did you remove you answer? i upvoted you as well. I accepted Matt answer because he answered a few minutes earlier than you.

Comment: Thanks Kashif, Our answers were virtually the same and his answer did post first.  There's always next time. :-)